# Trying to find a urban-fantasy novel. Romantic comedy about greek gods and muses

Tags: story-identification

I remember it was on my sophomore year or high school where I came across this novel so it was probably 2010 or 2011. It may not be anything special to people or be the highest or most amazing novel but I would like to find it, if not for nostalgia's sake. I found it in the adult section for romance books that were small paperback novels.

I don't think it was a series, just a novel about a muse.
The nine muses in Greek mythology were goddesses of the arts and sciences, and were daughters of Zeus, the king of the gods, and Mnemosyne, the goddess of memory.

These are the list of muses. I just copied it from some site (shameless I know, but when you're desperate....)

Thalia - Muse of comedy and idyllic poetry.
Melpomene - Muse of tragedy.
Cleo - Muse of history.
Euterpe - Muse of lyric poetry. (**This is probably the main character**)
Terpsichore - Muse of music and dancing.
Erato - Muse of erotic poetry.
Calliope - Muse of epic poetry and rhetoric. (**or this**)
Urania - Muse of astronomy.
Polyhymnia or Polymnia - Muse of sacred hymns and harmony. (**IDK**)

The main character is a muse. In this universe, the Greek gods are still functioning in modern society with Zeus being a major CEO of a corporation or something. I don't know which muse is the main character but I was think it may either be Euterpe or Calliope because the muse was stated as being the most unknown and useless in modern society.

So Zeus basically decrees that she needs to find her place in the world or else (I don't remember the or else, maybe she would disappear or die from being useless or something). (Maybe it was fall in love or compose something.) All I can remember is the conflict between herself the world, her purpose, and Zeus. I'm not sure if there was romance as I read it for the interesting aspect of Greek Mythology. It was an interesting read and I hope to find it again someday. **Also her name is not Muse and she is not beyond the Veil, no.**

Comment: Also there where she complains about how her sisters fare better than her in the current era. She may be a fictional muse with a completely original name and purpose. It has crossed my mind. I'm really sorry. my mind is all jumbled and my memories aren't that clear.

Comment: I might have read something like this at some point, but I don't remember...

Comment: Yeah! It's like a small paperback novel with one of those near stock pics that don't really grab your attention unlike the personalized fantasy novels! Like an Nicolas sparks novel...generic picture but the content was pretty good. it kind of reminds me of those small novels you read at starbucks or some other coffee shop.

Comment: I found this https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01GF9YK32/ref=series_dp_rw_ca_2 close but no cigar. MOVING FORWARD!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. I've done it. I've found the beast. Now to answer my own question.

Here [it is](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1268181.Almost_a_Goddess). Like I said, nothing spectacular, easy read. :) Now I can read it again. Ah yes, I can finally go to bed. *pats back*

...I'm really stubborn.

**Almost a Goddess (Goddess #1)**, by Judi McCoy.

[image: cover]

> Kyra's performance has, quite frankly, been a disappointment over these past one hundred years. Our Muse of Good Fortune, despite her exceptional charm and unearthly beauty, has been slacking off, getting by on her looks, wiles, and considerable sex appeal -- not to mention her privileged position as the daughter of Mighty Zeus Himself!

Also, if any of you want to read a series similar to the mythology discussed and you don't mind children's books. I recommend Kate McMullan's Myth-o-mania book series, Bruce Coville's Magic Shop books, and P.B. Kerr's Children of the Lamp series.